# Possible to add offset to the right of an element in a Zurb Foundation 4 grid?

Tags: offset, zurb-foundation, grid-layout

According to [Foundation's docs on the grid component](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/grid.html), I can essentially make 1 or more grid columns a space using their offset classes:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="large-1 columns">1st column</div>
  <div class="large-9 large-offset-2 columns">2 spaces to the left of this column</div>
</div>
```

That will make 1 column, then 2 columns of plain space and the 9 columns. Is it possible to make those offsets to the right of an element instead of the left? For example, something like this?

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="large-1 columns">1st column</div>
  <div class="large-9 large-offset-right-2 columns">2 spaces to the right</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you show a visual of what you're trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Assuming I understand your request correctly, it sounds like you just need to use `end` instead of `offset`. For example,

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="large-1 columns a">1st column</div>
    <div class="large-9 columns end">2 spaces to the left of this column</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This does work! Why do you have an `a` class in the 1st column `div`? Why do I not see the `end` class documented anywhere in the Foundation Grid docs??

Comment: @at. they haven't migrated that info to the V4 docs. It's [documented on the V3 page](http://foundation.zurb.com/old-docs/f3/grid.php).

Comment: Awesome! Since it worked, can you pretty please check the answer as correct? I'm hungry for them 15 points hahaha... It is in the docs, or at least, this `http://foundation.zurb.com/old-docs/f3/grid.php`. That's how I knew to use it. Oh, the "a" is from `https://gist.github.com/CL75/4657937`, a gist I made to quickly color any element so I can check positioning. Feel free to use it but watch out for potential overrides (i.e. if you have your own class of "a", "b" etc. The "a" is irrelevant to making `end` work, I forgot to strip it out, sorry for the confusion!

Comment: strange that they haven't migrated this to v4 docs. It's quite a useful helper class, just like `.collapse` which is nowhere in the docs (CMIIW) but a massive helper if you want your grid without padding in its columns.